Zeta Regularization
I am interested in applying the zeta regularization method to regularize
$$\zeta_2(s=-1/2)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} (2l+1)(l(l+1))^{1/2}.$$
In section 4.5 of the book "Zeta Regularization Techniques with Applications" by Elizalde et al., a calculation was carried out on this topic. On page 126, it is mentioned that:

The usual prescription in zeta function regularization is to take the principal part of the pole

Despite the understanding that the goal is to mitigate infinities by utilizing the residue of the pole, I seek a detailed proof of this concept. Through this approach, all instances of $$\zeta_2(s)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} (2l+1)(l(l+1))^{-s}\tag{4.5.34}$$ are expected to yield the same value for any $s$.
None of the references mentioned in the text provide an explicit proof of this method.

@AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks for your point on the lower limit of the sum. You are right, I made a mistake. I correct it. But my main concern is not solved yet. In the mentioned text , it is written : $\zeta_2 (s) = \sum_{l=1}^{\inf} (2l+1)(l(l+1))^{-s} = -2.65096$  where the index 2 is the dimension and the final numerical value is the summation of the residues.Clearly, this result is independent of the $s$ and I don't get it why.

Hard to say, but quite likely the claim is not that the result is independent of $s$, but rather that the sum, analytically continued in $s$, and then evaluated at $s=-1/2$, yields $-2.65...$. Although I'm not sure about this either: another summation method gives $$\sum_{l=1}^\infty(2l+1)(l(l+1))^{1/2}e^{-\epsilon l}=\frac{4}{\epsilon^3}+\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}+\frac{1}{4\epsilon}+\text{finite}$$ where the finite part is $$-\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n n (2 n+1)!! }{2^{n+2} (n+3)!}\zeta (n+1)=-0.30676221\dots$$ Do you have a closed-form expression for your $2.65\dots$?

@AccidentalFourierTransform No, I don't have a closed-form. Actually, I need a closed form, and I just find this in Elizalde's book. By the way, Would you let me know more about the method you present (I a mean the above zeta function with exponential coefficient)? I mean is there any reference which I read more about it in details?

I'm going to assume that the problem is well-posed and whatever reasonable regularization method to be used should be stable, so I can add and subtract stuff at will. If this assumption doesn't hold we are pretty much at sea anyway.
Notice that
$$
(2l+1)(l(l+1))^{1/2}\equiv f(l)+2l^2+2l+1/4
$$
where
$$
f(l):=(2l+1)(l(l+1))^{1/2}-(2l^2+2l+1/4)
$$
The point of this trivial statement is that $f(l)=\mathcal O(1/l^2)$ and therefore the sum
$$
\sum_{l=1}^\infty f(l)
$$
converges by itself, and we need not worry about regularizing. One can easily check that this sum equals
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n n (2 n+1)!! }{2^{n+2} (n+3)!}\zeta (n+1)=-0.0150955\dots
$$
Note that the same expression arises in $e^{-\epsilon l}$ regularization, cf. the comment section.
So this means that the only open problem is the sum
$$
\sum_{l=1}^\infty 2l^2+2l+1/4\tag{$\star$}
$$
For this, you can use whatever method you like the most. For example, one can assign
\begin{align}
\sum_{l=1}^\infty 2l^2&=2\biggl[\sum_{l=1}^\infty l^s\biggr]_{s=2}=2\zeta(-s)|_{s=2}=0\\
\sum_{l=1}^\infty 2l&=2\biggl[\sum_{l=1}^\infty l^s\biggr]_{s=1}=2\zeta(-s)|_{s=1}=-1/6\\
\sum_{l=1}^\infty 1/4&=(1/4)\biggl[\sum_{l=1}^\infty l^s\biggr]_{s=0}=(1/4)\zeta(-s)|_{s=0}=-1/8
\end{align}
so all in all, the original sum equals
$$
-0.0150955-7/24=-0.30676\dots
$$
which agrees with the result in the comment section using a different regulator.
Clearly this is different from the claim in the book. Hard to say what they were doing. But we do note that
$$
-\frac52+10(-0.0150955\dots)=-2.650955\dots
$$
which is the same number as in the OP, numerology notwithstanding. Perhaps we are not allowed to break up the sum in $(\star)$ into three terms for some reason? This would not explain the factor of $10$ anyway...

Thanks for your detailed explanation. May I have two other question about your suggested process? First, I can't derive the closed form for $\sum f(l)=\sum \frac{(−1)^n n(2n+1)!!}{2^{n+2}(n+3)!}ζ(n+1)$. The equation I derived is the subtraction of two Hurwitz Zeta function which cannot be written in the closed form. Second, I can't drive the value -0.0150955, even with Mathematica regularization command. It is appreciated if you clear these two for me

@Astrolabe You can accelerate convergence by adding more subtractions by hand, so you write e.g. $(2l+1)(l(l+1))^{1/2}\equiv g(l)+2l^2+2l+1/4-\frac{1}{64 l^2}+\frac{1}{64 l^3}-\frac{7}{512 l^4}+\frac{3}{256 l^5}$. These new terms can be summed explicitly, so the following Mathematica code gives the answer: NSum[(2l+1)(l(l+1))^(1/2)-(2l^2+2l+1/4-1/(64 l^2)+1/(64 l^3)-7/(512 l^4)+3/(256 l^5)),{l,1,20}]-\[Pi]^2/384+Zeta[3]/64-(7 \[Pi]^4)/46080+(3 Zeta[5])/256, which yields -0.0150955
